# Writing a SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 and I have a table called "AgDate" with 4 columns that looks like the following:

```
Date           ID      One     Two
2011-01-01     A1      Yes  
2011-01-01     A1               Yes
2011-01-02     A1      Yes  
2011-01-03     A1               Yes
2011-01-03     A2               Yes
```

I need to write a query that will return only rows in which the same date has "Yes" in column "One" and "Two".  For this example, the query will only return the first two rows because they are the same date and have "Yes" for both columns.  I will like to be able to run the query for a specific range of dates if that is possible?  Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Do you specifically require both rows to be returned, or would it be sufficient to return only the relevant date (in this case, `2011-01-01`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do this using conditions in the `where` clause:

```
select a.*
from agdate a
where exists (select 1 from agdate a2 where a2.date = a.date and a2.one = 'yes') and
      exists (select 1 from agdate a2 where a2.date = a.date and a2.two = 'yes');
```

This is standard SQL so it should run in any database.

Comment: PostgreSQL and SQL Server need either `where date in (select date...` or `where exists (select 1...` in the WHERE clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f840a/1) Error message is "Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int". PostgreSQL error message is similar. Working [where date in (select date...](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f840a/2) syntax. Working [where exists (select 1...](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f840a/3) syntax.

Comment: I feel stupid every day. I thought I knew what you meant; I upvoted your answer before I left my comment.